# Linux: Limit CPU and memory consumption of a group of processes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, resource-management

On a modern Ubuntu Server machine we need to host about twenty web-applications. (More apps would be added later.)

Each application is a nginx virtual host, which talks to a group of identical long-living FCGI processes (written inhouse), via Unix Domain Socket.

FCGI processes are different for each web-application, but still pretty similar to each other (just some minor business logic differences).

Normally, we would allocate one Xen virtual machine for each web-application. But in this case, the memory overhead is too great — the processes are lightweight and normally would not affect each other or compete for resources. We would like to host all this stuff in a single Xen VM.

However, there is a slight chance that due to some unforeseen bug a FCGI process would go rogue and eat all CPU and / or memory on the machine, affecting other web-applications.

We would like to isolate web-applications from each other, to minimize chances that problems in one web-app would affect others.

CPU and memory resources are the main concerns. It would be nice to other control things like IO throughput etc., but I've got a feeling that if we would get too pedantic on that, it is better to use Xen anyway, memory costs would be negligible when compared to system management work costs. In practice, in our specific case, we consider other things than CPU and memory starvation to be low-risk problems, and if that will happen, we'll accept that other web-apps will initially suffer.

The question is: what is the proper way to limit CPU and memory consumption for a group of processes in our case?

Comment: Android phones(linux) do this by running each application as a separate user-id with limits on them, I second @symcbean's response below too though, there really isn't a 'right way' to do this.  Each way will have trade-offs.

Comment: @polynominal: How to properly limit CPU rate? Limiting cpu core affinity is not a solution (I have much more processes than cores.) And I'm not sure if renicing a priority would give me a manageable limit...

Comment: You can use http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706 to limit each user to only X% of the CPU.

Comment: @polynominal: Sorry for a late reply. Your suggestion actually makes sense, I think, please post it as an answer, so I can accept / upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the "proper" way is (and I suspect that there isn't one). Apart from using a virtual machine....

You can limit scheduling of a process using (re)nice (spawned processes inherit priority from their parent). You can ringfence a process (or process group) to a single cpu using taskset. And various memory usage limits can be set using ulimit.

> there is a slight chance that due to some unforeseen bug a FCGI process would go rogue and eat all CPU and / or memory

Maybe you should consider a watchdog?

Depending on the volume of traffic and the perfromance reuirements, perhaps using CGI rather than FCGI might be an idea?

Comment: CGI is not good performance-wise. Home-grown watchdogs are usually brittle, I would prefer a ready-made solution.